# Where is lodash.js after install via npm?

Tags: javascript, npm, lodash

I ran npm insall lodash but I can't find the lodash.js file to include in the browser.  I realize I can just download lodash.js but I would prefer to use npm if possible.

Comment: Look in `node_modules`.  However, you should use Browserify instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of lodash packages replace lodash.js with index.js.  Use node_modules/lodash/index.js.

Answer (score 0):

npm installs all of the modules in to the `node_modules` folder.  So you'd find lodash in `./node_modules/lodash/`

If you're using browserify, you don't need to worry about that location as you can simply `var _ = require('lodash');` and browserify will take care of the files for you.

**More info on Browserify at:** http://browserify.org/

Comment: I'm asking where the lodash.js file is inside of the lodash folder.  I can't find it anywhere.  Normally, I can use npm to install a package and then include it in my html like so; 'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js', but there is no lodash.js.  I'm also trying to avoid an additional install tool.  Angular and Browserify do not place well together out of the box.

Comment: When I install lodash it shows as node_modules/lodash/lodash.js

Comment: Its definitely not there for me.  Are you adding any flags to npm install lodash?

Comment: Nope, just "npm install lodash"

Comment: the new packaging does not have lodash.js by design.  https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1267.